# Van conversion electrics

Tags: dc, spark

I've been working on the electrics for my van and wondered if anyone could help me. I just accidentally touched some foil bubble wrap insulation to a piece of the van's metal work and it started the spark! This doesn't seem good to me. I disconnected my leisure battery and split charge relay but my multimeter is still reading that the van body has a voltage of 12.5v. Is this normal or have I done something wrong? Thanks in advance

Comment: Welcome!  Might be better served at https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Voltage is a 2-point measurement. So you were measuring 12.5V from your van's body *to what other point*?

Comment: The positive terminal of the van battery

Comment: A cars/vans body is usually connected to the 'negative' terminal of the battery, so your multimeter reading is correct.

Comment: What else was the insulation touching?  It would need to touch 2 electrically connected objects to spark.

Comment: Isn't this dangerous though? having the potential for it to spark if touched by foil or the like?

Comment: To my knowledge it wasn't touching anything else that had an electrical connection

Comment: It must have been touching something else other than the bodywork.  Are there any wires nearby?

Comment: It would be useful to see a photo of where you are working.

Comment: What is a leisure battery? What is a split charge relay?

Comment: Give me a mo HandyHowie and ill get you a picture. I think I have solved the issue. My latest theory is that the foil insulation was momentarily touching the positive of the battery as well as the foot of the passenger seat, therefore creating a short circuit and sparking...this is plausible as the car battery was uncovered and very nearby at the time

Comment: That would explain it.

Comment: @Hearth A leisure battery is a more rugged car battery that is often used in caravans etc for powering the lights, tv, fridge.  A split charge relay is a relay that connects the leisure battery to the car’s charging circuit once the engine is running.